# Sending data from broadcastreceiver to a custom thread in android not working?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, broadcastreceiver

I have 3 threads : `UI Thread` (MainActity thread), `Thread1` and `Thread2`.
`UI Thread` starts `Thread1` and `Thread1` starts `Thread2`

There is a MainActity class variable that I want to instantiate. What I did was using `MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {...}` to instantiate a `TextView` from a broadcastReceiver. But I thought that `Thread2` would have the new value of that text view. It does not. It still has the initial value (i.e before the private boradcastreceiver alters it. How can I get the new value in `Thread2` ?

Below is how my code looks like :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView mytxtView; //Use to bind a TextView from UI layout

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mytxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytxtView);
        mytxtView.setText("Value 1");
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
                thread1.start();
        }

        public void onResume() {
            registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SOME_TELEPHONY_INTENT_ACTION"))
        }

        private class Thread1 extends Thread{
           @Override
        public void run() {
           Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Thread2());
                thread2.start();
         }
        }

        private class Thread2 extends Thread{
           @Override
        public void run() {

         Thread.sleep(45000) ; //just to make sur myReceiver does its job
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),myTxtView.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
// This shows "Value 1" instead of "Value 2"
         }
        }

        BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              if (intent.getAction().
                    equals("android.provider.Telephony.SOME_TELEPHONY_INTENT_ACTION")){
              //do some work

               MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                myTxtView.setText("Value 2");
                            }
            }}
    }
```

Comment: First Please follow SO guidelines to form a question [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and put some log and see sequence in which your threads and broadcast is being executed as expected or not

Comment: `MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread()` .You do not have to use that function. You can just set the text for a textview in onReceive().

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh How about now ? I've update the code

Comment: @greenapps Yeah. That is true. I've tried it before. But it's not solving the problem... Please see my updated code. It's as if `Thread 2` was only seeing an outdated version of `UI Thread` heap.. If at all possible

Answer (score 1):

Issue : your are just registering your broadcast but your are never triggering it so you need to trigger the broadcast to to execute `onReceive` method using `sendBroadcast(yourBroadcastIntent).`

Try

```
public void onResume() {
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SOME_TELEPHONY_INTENT_ACTION"));
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(""android.provider.Telephony.SOME_TELEPHONY_INTENT_ACTION""));        
   }
```

And no need of `runOnUiThread` in receiver , as @greenapps has already mentioned it as well

And it `setText` to set the text as

```
myTxtView.setText("Value 2");
```

though seems like a typo `info.myTxtView("Value 2");`

**Update** : [`Working Project files repo`](https://github.com/Pavneet-Sing/community_solutions/tree/master/Android/ThreadsAndBroadcastReceiverUpdateIssue) along with screenshot to demonstrate the working state with provided screenshot.

Comment: Yeah it was a typo.... I don't know why it's an issue. Whether I use `sendBroadcast` as you've suggested or not, the BroadcastReceiver does its job (maybe it's `android.provider.Telephony` related). And yes I did not need to use `runOnUiThread`.... Anyway, this did not solve my issue. The `Thread2` is stiil printing `Value 1` instead of `Value 2`... I have no idea what's going on...Though, in `MainActivity` `myTextView` value becomes `Value 2`, in `Thread2` it is still `Value 1` that is printed...

Comment: @Bloomberg58 i don't know what you are trying but to prove the validity of my answer, i have provided the code link along with screenshot